# How to crop an image converted to Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, image, crop

I have an image converted to base64-string. I convert base64-string to Uint8Array by code:

```
const BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
  const base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
  const base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
  const raw = window.atob(base64);
  const rawLength = raw.length;
  const array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
  for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
    array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

I don't know how to crop it. Can you help me to implement the algorithm?

Comment: use canvas to crop that image, you have a data uri already, print that image on a canvas element then crop it, no need to go through all these hoops, especially since it doesn't seem like you even know the dimensions of the picture.

Comment: Overall I agree with mpm's comment, but if you must do this mathematically you'll need to know the image's width and height. Do you know these ahead of time? If not you'll have to parse the base64 string for them and things get kind of complex.

Comment: Yes, I know image's width and height. Thank you for comments, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, mpm and YAHsaves. 
I decided to use canvas and it works easy and quickly.
Here is the link to [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas_image_processing). I hope, it can help other people to crop and resize images in browser using canvas.